# How to extend text within a div in responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design, stylesheet

Hi stackoverflow community. I am building a responsive page and at the moment I am styling elements to show on mobile devices. I have got three elements within the div where image and teaser seem to perfectly fit after small styling adjustment. However, the headline despite width:100% specification doesn't fill up the space as it should. The problem is that the other div is dropping words of the text later than the top one when the page gets minimized. It just doesn't look estetic. I am a bit stuck tried different stylings, but it is still not working.
Below I provide a CSS code for the div I have a trouble with if this is not enough to see the problem, please do let me know and I will post the full HTML for both elements and also css for responsive and original styling:

```
.list_of_reviews_1 {  /* this is a div's css*/
    width:100%;
    top:40px;
    left:-45px;
    border:solid;

}

.list_of_reviews_1 li {  /*this is a headline*/
    left:-41px;
    width:100%;
    top:40px;
    margin:auto;
}

.list_of_reviews_1 img { /*image*/
    left:0px;

}

.list_of_reviews_1 p { /*teaser*/
    top:50px;
    margin:auto;
    width:100%;

}
```

Please see the code below as per request:
HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<link href="example.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="list_of_reviews_1">
<ul style="list-style-type:none">
<li>What will happen to Brittish travelers when Brexit finaly happens</li>
</ul>
<img src="for left column.jpg" height="150" width="150" alt="What will happen to Brittish travelers when Brexit finaly happens"/>
<p>Moreblablabla</p>
</div>
<div class="right_column">
<p class="most">Most popular</p> 
<ul  style="list-style-type:none">
<li>What will happen to Brittish travelers when Brexit finaly happens</li>
</ul>

<img src="for left column.jpg" height="150" width="150" alt="What will happen to Brittish travelers when Brexit finaly happens"/>
<p>ufisuhodsiuhosiughig</p>
</div>
</html>
</body>
```

and CSS:

```
.list_of_reviews_1 {
    position:relative;
    width:65%;
    top:-38px;
    margin-left: 45px;
}

.list_of_reviews_1 img {
    position:relative;
    top:40px;
}

.list_of_reviews_1 p {
    position:relative;
    top:-48px;
    width:54%;
    margin-left:170px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, Serif;
}

.list_of_reviews_1 li {
    position:relative;
    top:110px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, Serif;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 30px;
    width:70%;
    margin-left:130px;
}




.right_column {
    position:relative;
    height:45%;
    width:35%;
    top:-2024px;
    margin-left: 790px;

}

.most {
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, Serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 35%;
    margin-left: 145px;
    float:centre;
}
.right_column ul {
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, Serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 590px;
}

.right_column img {
    position:relative;
    top:-30px;
    margin-left:150px;
}

.teaser {
    position:relative;
    top:-20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:850px) {
.list_of_reviews_1 {
    width:100%;
    top:40px;
    left:-45px;
    border:solid;

}

.list_of_reviews_1 li {
    left:-41px;
    width:100%;
    top:40px;
    margin:auto;
}

.list_of_reviews_1 img {
    left:0px;

}

.list_of_reviews_1 p {
    top:50px;
    margin:auto;
    width:100%;

}

.right_column {
        width:100%;
        top:1140px;
        left:-790px;
        border:solid;
}

.most {
    left:-145px;
}
.right_column img {
    left:-145px;

}
}
```

I know the code is quite long, but these are all necessary parts to understand the problem. The main problem is in the media query as in the 'list_of_reviews_1 li'

Comment: Hey! Can you please provide a MCV Example of your issue?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Try removing left style on the headline, If you want better help we will need to also see your HTML.

Comment: Hi innit fail. Tried that and my div got moved to the right :)

Comment: Hi Juan, Please see the code. I have checked it and it is working on my end exactly with the issue I have explained.

Comment: Hi innit fail, sorry for my earlier reply. I removed left in the div not the headline. Done it in the headline, no changes, kind of tells that 'left' wasn't necessary there